# ParaView: matlab surf counterpart?

Tags: paraview

Given 2D data (a scalar field), I want to plot the scalar value in the third dimension (landscape). How can I achieve that?

ParaView 4.1.0; example data (`example.vtu`):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<VTKFile type="Unstructured Grid"  version="0.1"  >
<UnstructuredGrid>
<Piece  NumberOfPoints="9" NumberOfCells="8">
<Points>
<DataArray  type="Float64"  NumberOfComponents="3"  format="ascii">0 0 0  0.5 0 0  1 0 0  0 0.5 0  0.5 0.5 0  1 0.5 0  0 1 0  0.5 1 0  1 1 0  </DataArray>
</Points>
<Cells>
<DataArray  type="UInt32"  Name="connectivity"  format="ascii">0 1 4  0 3 4  1 2 5  1 4 5  3 4 7  3 6 7  4 5 8  4 7 8  </DataArray>
<DataArray  type="UInt32"  Name="offsets"  format="ascii">3 6 9 12 15 18 21 24 </DataArray>
<DataArray  type="UInt8"  Name="types"  format="ascii">5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 </DataArray>
</Cells>
<PointData  Scalars="f_3"> 
<DataArray  type="Float64"  Name="f_3"  format="ascii">1.0000000000000000e+00  1.0000000000000000e+00  1.0000000000000000e+00  1.0000000000000000e+00  1.0476190476190479e+00  1.0000000000000000e+00  1.0000000000000000e+00  1.0000000000000000e+00  1.0000000000000000e+00  </DataArray> 
</PointData> 
</Piece>
</UnstructuredGrid>
</VTKFile>
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason I'm not able to load your dataset, anyway, since you have a pointdata scalar array, you can try the warpbyscalar filter.