# matlab surf feature in VTK format

Tags: matlab, vtk, stl-format

I have the following matlab code:

```
clear all
close all
clc

np = 10; % number of points along cylinder height
nc = 15; % points in circumference

h = 5.;  % cylinder height
r = 1.; % cylinder radius

t = linspace(0, 2*pi, nc); % angle in rad
dh = h/(np-1); % height difference between two points

for i = 1:np
    for j = 1:nc

        x(i,j) = r*cos(t(j));
        y(i,j) = r*sin(t(j));
        z(i,j) = (i-1) * dh;

    end
end

% a colormap for reference, i am using sthing else in my code
f = sqrt(x.^2 + y.^2 + z.^2);

subplot(1,2,1)
surf(x,y,z,f)
axis equal

subplot(1,2,2)
mesh(x,y,z,f)
axis equal
```

That generates a mesh out of a cylinder shape. Now, I can convert this grid file to stl format with [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/4512-surf2stl) script entering the command `surf2stl('test.stl',x,y,z,'ascii')`  and can open it with paraview.

But in that case if it's stl i loose the colormap (f variable from matlab script). What I want is either to be possible to have stl with shaded surfaces. OR i would prefer if I could export this mesh to a VTK file format but I don't know how. So I am looking how to convert matlab's surf or mesh data to VTK format. (edit: Or a third option to convert matlab grid to stl and then convert stl to vtk and add the scalar f to vtk file).

I searched first in stackoverflow for possible duplicates but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22380153/paraview-matlab-surf-counterpart) is not the same and doesn't have an answer.

Comment: Not what you are looking for, but you can get the same cylinder coordinates by replacing your `for` loop (and the 2 lines above) by `[x,y,z]=cylinder(r*ones(np,1),nc-1 ); z=z*5;`

Comment: @Hoki it's just a reference simple example, I actually have quite different mesh but if I find the answer for this cylinder example, then it will work for my case as well.